# localhost return headers and content different from 127.0.0.1 or local IP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to return an mp4 video using spring boot.
The problem is when I access the controller method using localhsot:

```
http://localhsot:8080/files/videos/mission0.mp4
```

it return:

```
Content-Type →video/mp4
Date →Thu, 11 Aug 2016 17:41:30 GMT
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Application-Context →application
```

and the video played in the browser, 
but when I use 127.0.0.1 or the local IP instead of localhost it return:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →close
Pragma →no-cache
```

and no video returned.

here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/videos/{fileName:.+}")
public void getVideo(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {

    byte[] video = fileService.getFileBytes(videoDir, fileName);
    ByteInputStream videoStream = new ByteInputStream(video, video.length);

    try {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
        IOUtils.copy(videoStream, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException("Error while rendering the video");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you open command prompt and try running
 ping 127.0.0.1

This will help verify that loopback address is working fine or not.

Comment: Loopback has to be working as `localhost` gets converted to the loopback IP when the request is made.

Comment: its working fine, and other api end points (that return json or images) working ok.

Comment: @ShawnClark Could you please try the code on your machine ?

Comment: I can't really "try the code" as you have some specifics around loading a video. If you can create the project on GitHub or something similar that runs (including a test mp4 video) then I can try it. In general though there isn't anything unique around the code you are showing.